# Having trouble using cli to switch between playback devices with pipewire

Tags: command-line, audio, i3, pipewire, garuda-linux

I've been going down the i3wm road of pain and can't for the life of me understand how to change the output device with cli commands.

Setup:

- Using i3-gaps (Base Distro is Garuda Linux)
- pipewire is the audio provider
- When using pavucontrol I can switch between my Headphones and Speakers as the output port but can't seem to figure what is changing in the background with pactl, wpctl, aplay
- I have headphones connected to my front aux panel and speakers connected to the rear aux panel.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Update: Found a solution and posted it in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution and wrote a short script for it

```
if [[ $(pactl list | grep "Active Port: analog-output") == *"headphones"* ]]; then
    pactl set-sink-port 0 analog-output-lineout
else
    pactl set-sink-port 0 analog-output-headphones
fi
```

Also added this to my i3config:

```
bindsym F6 exec --no-startup-id sh ~/path/to/script/switch_output.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

With `pactl list short sinks` you should be able to list your sinks, your output devices and with `pactl info` you get information about the actual configuration. The `Default Sink` should name the actual output.

To switch the default sink, you can use `pactl set-default-sink <sink_name>`.

I found a script online, that switches through the possible sinks each time it is called: https://ericlathrop.com/2021/02/changing-pulseaudio-outputs-programmatically/

Allthough it says it is for pulse, it works (at least for me) with pipewire as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, they were both on the same sink for me but I found a solution and will add it to the main post

Answer (score 0):

I had to first set the card profile, then the default sink.

Here's an example of what worked for me:

```
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_Solo_USB_...
pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_Solo_USB_....HiFi__hw_USB__sink
```

I used autocomplete to select the string.